Ssh.Authenticate Fails after received banner
Getting "invalid login and/or password error" but username and password are correct.
The session log seems to show a failure immediately after the banner.
The detailed logs are below.
Any advice welcome please, been stuck on this for a while now.
Session Log:
TRAN* Established TCP/IP connection with SSH server
TRAN> SSH-2.0-Chilkat_9.5.0.99
TRAN< SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
TRAN> KEXINIT
TRAN< KEXINIT
TRAN* Key Algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
TRAN* Host Key Algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
TRAN* Out Encryption: rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,arcfour,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,cast128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
TRAN* In Encryption: rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,arcfour,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,cast128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
TRAN* Out MAC: hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
TRAN* In MAC: hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
TRAN* Out Compress: none,zlib@openssh.com
TRAN* In Compress: none,zlib@openssh.com
TRAN> SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
TRAN< KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP/KEXDH_REPLY
TRAN* ED25519 host key signature verified
TRAN> NEWKEYS
TRAN< NEWKEYS
TRAN* SSH Key Exchange Success.
TRAN> IGNORE
TRAN> SERVICE_REQUEST: ssh-userauth
TRAN< SERVICE_ACCEPT
TRAN> USERAUTH_REQUEST (none)
TRAN< USERAUTH_BANNER
TRAN< USERAUTH_FAILURE
TRAN> USERAUTH_REQUEST (password)
TRAN< USERAUTH_FAILURE
TRAN* Partial success: 0
TRAN* Auth list: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password


and the Chilkat Log
ChilkatLog:
   AuthenticatePw_ssh(6344ms):
    DllDate: Jun 28 2024
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.99
    UnlockStatus: 1
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: .NET 4.6 / x64 / VS2015
    VerboseLogging: 1
    authenticatePw(6344ms):
      login: [n104559]
      sshServerVersion: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
      sshAuthenticatePw(6344ms):
        requestUserAuthService:
          sendServiceRequest:
            svcName: ssh-userauth
            SentServiceReq: ssh-userauth
          --sendServiceRequest
          ssh-userauth service accepted.
        --requestUserAuthService
        [SSH] Received USERAUTH_BANNER
        AuthMethods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
        passwordAuth(6328ms):
          Sent login/password
          Authentication failed or partial success. (1)
          PartialSuccess1: 0
          AuthList: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
          important:
            This is likely a simple invalid login and/or password error,
            meaning your application did not send the correct login and/or password.
          --important
        --passwordAuth
      --sshAuthenticatePw
    --authenticatePw
    Failed.
  --AuthenticatePw_ssh
--ChilkatLog



You could check the syslogs on the remote server to see if the sshd process is logging the reason for the authentication failure. Have you tried connecting with the ssh command-line utility? Are you able to log in using that?

Ssh command line works OK. I will get someone on the other end involved. Thanks
